# OGR to OGR looking for WFS to MSSQL code

Tags: sql, convert, wfs, ogr

I'm trying to get a WFS converting to MSSQL using Ogr2ogr.  I have used the following code but get an error of unable to open WFS source.

Here is my attempt.  Path/UID/Password are all correct.

: Set the environment to use the OGR libraries supplied with the MapManager3
SET MapManagerPATH=C:\Program Files\MapManager30
SET PATH=%MapManagerPATH%;%PATH%
SET GDAL_DATA=%MapManagerPATH%
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%MapManagerPATH%\gdalplugins
SET PROJ_LIB=%MapManagerPATH%\ProjLib

ogr2ogr -lco geom_name:geom -t_srs epsg:28350 -nln "service_dbyd_wfs" -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:Server=SERVERNAME;database=DBNAME" "WFS:https://URL_etc/ows[?TYPENAME=TicketAccessJobs],UserID=USERID;UserPwd=USERPASSWORD"

pause

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: the examples on https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html should get you started